# Is there any difference between a track made from 2oz copper, or one plated to 2oz

Tags: pcb

Is there a difference in reliability if I start with  a copper clad board with 2oz copper vs starting with 1oz and letting them plate up to 2oz?   Intuitively I would say no but someone put the idea in my head that somehow the plating layer could de-laminate.  Has anyone had any experience with that.

Comment: I can assure you that copper plated on copper will never "delaminate", at least not before the whole trace lifts from the PCB substrate. The plating is a necessary production step for most boards since copper has to be added to the inside surfaces of holes and vias to make them conductive, the extra thickness is a bonus. Keep in mind that the *inside* layers won't be plated.

Comment: @jms: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: If you have a board with significant current running through the traces/planes, you may want to check the difference in resistance between the two materials.  Copper is an excellent conductor, and the plating will certainly not be copper.  You could potentially have a very hot spot on your board if the resistance is significantly different.

Answer (score 1):

Any time you're plating, you're not going to have the same strength as you would get with a solid piece of copper. With that said, when delamination occurs, the void usually occurs within the insulator, not at the plating surface.[image: delamination1][image: delamination2]

Why are you considering building up to 2oz with plating instead of just going straight for 2oz? Is this an attempt to precisely control the thickness?